# PC randomly freezes under light load

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, amd-radeon

I recently got a new pc with the following parts (https://pcpartpicker.com/list/XvKkb8) and I randomly endure crashes.

Basically, my PC would randomly cut all audio in my headphones, the monitor would freeze for seconds and then my monitor will say that it has no signal. The event viewer shows no errors except the error of the PC not shutting off properly when i boot it up since to get it off the frozen state, I need to use the power button. I really can't understand why its happening. I'm running brand new parts and the most recent drivers.

More info about the crashes, they almost never happen under load. They usually happen when I'm doing casual browsing with the only thing opened at the moment being Firefox, Discord and Spotify, sometimes even Steam but I don't have anything running there at the time. Today it happened while I was rendering something in Blender but I honestly think it was mostly random.

Another thing I noticed is the fact that every time it crashes, I hear something coming from some part which I can't identify. It's like an HDD writing at even intervals, somewhat louder than usual. I am not sure if it's an HDD or if it's another part but I don't think it's a fan.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If it truly is a hang of the computer that doesn't recover after say 30 minutes, the accepted troubleshooting procedure is to capture a complete/active memory dump for analysis.  To do so you have to set up the computer in advance to: 1) Create a complete or active dump where possible. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/generate-kernel-or-complete-crash-dump  2) Configure the registry such that you can trigger a bugcheck using the keyboard. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard . That should work.

Comment: I haven't waited 30 minutes for sure, but it doesn't fix itself after 15-20 minutes for sure. Will do those things now.

Comment: I suggest you also update BIOS, and all drivers. Then get memtest86.exe and run a couple of passes to check your memory completely. Then run a full scan with Windows Defender to check for viruses

Comment: Run a check on your HD while you're at it. That is where I would expect that noise to be coming from